# Android Resource Not Found after inflating Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an Activity Layout which has 2 CardViews:
CardView1 has 1 ListView
CardView2 has 1 Integer (Final Amount)

```
public class CheckoutActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity implements AmountUpdateListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
    populateSevicesInCart();
}

private void populateSevicesInCart() {
    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_content_checkout_cartItemsListView);
    List<Service> services = CartDataAccessUtil.getServicesInCart();
    CheckoutListServicesAdapter checkoutListServicesAdapter = new CheckoutListServicesAdapter(this, this, services);
    view.setAdapter(checkoutListServicesAdapter);
}

public void updateAmountPayable(Integer grandTotal){
    TextView textViewAmountPayable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_content_checkout_amount_payable);
    textViewAmountPayable.setText(grandTotal);
}
```

Layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.callsalon.activity.CheckoutActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_checkout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout_content_checkout_mainContent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView_content_checkout_cartItemsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_content_checkout_amount_payable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Rs. 0"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class CheckoutListServicesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Service> services;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private CostAmounts costAmounts;
    private AmountUpdateListener listener;

    public CostAmounts getCostAmounts() {
        return costAmounts;
    }

    public CheckoutListServicesAdapter(Context context, AmountUpdateListener listener, List<Service> services) {
        super();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        this.services = services;
        this.listener = listener;
        updateCostAmounts(services);
    }

    private void updateCostAmounts(List<Service> services){
        costAmounts = new CostAmounts(services);
        listener.updateAmountPayable(costAmounts.getGrandTotal());

        User currentUser = UserDataAccessUtil.getUser();
        currentUser.setAmountPayable(costAmounts.getGrandTotal());
        UserDataAccessUtil.updateUser(currentUser);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        ..
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        ..
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    services = CartDataAccessUtil.getServicesInCart();
                    updateCostAmounts(services);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
        return serviceListRow;
    }
}
```

In the Activity onCreate, I set the adapter for ListView of CardView1.
My ListView has a Remove button. Once I click Remove button, The CardView1 behaves perfectly but i want to update the Integer in CardView2 every time I remove an item from ListView.

I tried:

1) In RemoveButton onClick, Saving context object and tried context.findViewById(R.id.final_amount). context doesn't have a findViewById method

2) Created an interface called amountUpdatedListener, implemented method in Activity. Passed the listener to adapter and called listener.amountUpdated(finalAmount) but still failing saying ResourceNotFoundException.

Comment: some code will help us find the problem

Comment: Added code in Question

Comment: context does not have findViewById. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html. And you post you stacktrace also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting Integer to a TextView

```
 textViewAmountPayable.setText(grandTotal);
```

Change to

```
 textViewAmountPayable.setText(String.valueOf(grandTotal.intValue()));
```

setText looks for a resource with the id. Id is an integer. If not found You get ResourceNorFoundException.

What you need is CharacerSequence. Look @ setText methods @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Found it. Blunder mistake. I thought Integer to String should be trivial. Since the compiler didnt cry, i didnt bother. but turned out (int) has different meaning